# Android drag imageview with finger behaves strange

Tags: java, android, imageview, drag, move

I'm implementing imageview drag function to my application.
I have tried with below code but it's behaves strange.when I try to drag the image 
it's changes the position and during the movement it's shows like zooming the image.
I want to move the image with finger smoothly.

please help me to solve this problem

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(mImagePreView.getLayoutParams());

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _xDelta = X - marginParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - marginParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            marginParams.leftMargin = X-_xDelta;
            marginParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            marginParams.rightMargin = -250;
            marginParams.bottomMargin = -250;

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
            mImagePreView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mImagePreView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.leftMargin += offsetX;
layoutParams.topMargin += offsetY;
```

And there is error:

```
    _xDelta = X - marginParams.leftMargin;
    _yDelta = Y - marginParams.topMargin;
```

X - events in absolute coordinates, marginParams.leftMargin - coordinates are relative to the parent layout